# Swing & Main method not found

Tags: java, swing

```
package org.yashwanth.gui;
import java.awt.Dimension;
// Dimension is an Object that helps to store heights and widths
import java.awt.Toolkit;
// Toolkit asks different question of the OS
import javax.swing.*;


public class framing extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new framing();

    }
    public framing(){
        this.setSize(400,400);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Error: Main method not found in class org.yashwanth.gui.framing, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: Don't like framing should be Framing (see java name conventions), but there is no error in your program, it probably depends on how you launch it.. show launch command

Comment: check that u save your code and if you use Eclipse - make sure that the class is selected before running it